# Is it a good practice to leave a database connection open on a node.js application?

Tags: node.js, database, connection, database-connection

I have seen examples from different `Node.js` frameworks in which a database connection is opened at the beginning of the app, and that same connection is reused all over the application. I have seen, for example, Mongoose being used this way, and it seems to be the case for `sequelize.js`.

Is this a good practice? Can a constantly open connection by hijacked? If not, what would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Why would you constantly close/open connections? When would you do that? For each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is good. You can still use pooling if you need to.
But generally having a single connection is better than opening a new connection everytime. 
Make sure though that you check 'error' events on the DB instance. So you can reconnect if the connection to DB is dropped. 
You can always have a hickup in your mysql server. For example when diskspace runs low or memory full issues.